# Square of matrix product equals product of squares

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A,B$ are two $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2$ if $AB=BA$.

We have $(AB)_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}$, so $(AB)^2_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (AB)_{ik}(AB)_{kj}$.

$(A^2B^2)_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n A^2_{ik}B^2_{kj}$

I'm kind of stuck here, I don't know how to further develop this into something fruitful.

Comment: Why not simply expand $(AB)^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing this. We have $(AB)^2 = (AB)(AB) = A(BA)B = A(AB)B = A^2 B^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing things element-by-element is a pain, and I personally consider it a last-resort technique.

As others pointed out in comments, this holds:

$$(AB)^2=(AB)(AB)=ABAB=A(BA)B=A(AB)B=AABB=A^2B^2$$

Where I used parentheses to hopefully make clear when I used the hypothesis $AB=BA$.